# Two MATLAB questions about syms

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I use matlab syms to define a function
f(x,y,z) = ||y-zx||^2
where x and y are vectors of R^5, z is a scalar in R as follows

```matlab
syms x y [5,1] matrix;
syms z;
f = (y-z*x).'*(y-z*x)
```

Now, I have two questions:

1. How to expand the expression of f using MATLAB?
2. How to define the function t-> d f(x+tw,y,z)/d t via an output of diff?

Thanks a lot for any comments and suggestions.

---

What I tried are summarized below:

1. How to expand the expression of f using MATLAB?

It seems that

```matlab
expand(f)
```

does not work! and the other functions such as `simplify`, `collect` and `factor` work neither. So I want to know how to expand and simplify this expression in the correct way?

2. How to define the function t-> d f(x+tw,y,z)/d t via an output of diff?

I have tried to define the function phi(t) = f(x+tw,y,z) first as

```matlab
syms x y w [5,1] matrix;
syms z t;
f = @(x,y,z) (y-z*x).'*(y-z*x);
phi = @(t) f(x+t*w,y,z);
```

Then I compute the derivative using diff:

```matlab
diff(phi(t),t);
```

But I don't know how to make the resulting expression as a function of t (so that I can evaluate the expression of phi'(1))? For the moment, I just copy the expression of phi'(t) computed by diff and define it manually. Hoping to get a better way to do so. Thanks a lot for any comments and suggestions.

Comment: As you can see, Stack Overflow doesn't do LaTeX. Please [edit] your post to replace the LaTeX expressions with something more readable. Also, you should ask a single question per post. It is OK to post multiple, related questions, as long as they are on-topic and suitable for the site. You can always add a link from the one to the other.

Comment: You might want to try using `dot`, as in this post: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/329997-symbolic-dot-product-of-symbolic-3d-vectors

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your comments. I modify my post with some visible maths' expressions. Concerning dot you suggested in that post, it seems that using .' as what I did will just simply solve his problem. But I am not sure how it will be helpful to my questions here. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: From what I read, `dot` will properly expand, as opposed to your way where you’re not getting the expanded expression. It might not work either, but you should try it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. I've just tried `dot`, unfortunately, it seems that `dot` is not available for symmatrix type object, i.e., I can not do something like `dot(x,y)` if x and y are defined as `syms x y [2,1] matrix`. Anyway, I doubt that the symmatrix type is not designed well enough to support `expand` yet and many other functions as `subs` and `simplify`...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to convert a `symmatrix` object to a string in Matlab. Once I have the string representation, I can replace the substring 't' with a desired value, and then evaluate the modified string to compute its value. Although this is not the final solution for defining a function of t, but it helps me achieve my objective automatically without having to manually copy expressions to define phi'(t).

BTW: `simplfy`,`expand` and `collect` functions for `symmatrix` objects are still unresolved problems.